# Which version of gedmo should I specify for Doctrine 2.1.7 with symofny2.0.15?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

My Bash refuse to process to a databse update since I've installed gedmo for S2.
I'm wondering if its because I've installed the wrong version of Gedmo.

I have Doctrine 2.1.7 and i need to install the 2.1.x version of gedmo-doctrine-extensions how can specify this to my deps file ?

For now I have

> [gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
>       git=http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git

But when trying to enter the doctrine:schema:update --force command, I have "Class 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\DefaultFileLocator' not found in (my path)\vendor\gedmo-doctrine-extension\lib\Gedmo\Mapping\ExtensionMetadataFactory.php on line 170"

So i'm assuming it is due to the version of gedmo I use, Am I Right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using 2.3.0 version for my project based on Symfony 2.0.15 and Doctrine 2.1.7

```
[gedmo-doctrine-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git
    version=v2.3.0
```

Anyhow you can look on http://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions.git to see what version you want/need and add it into your deps file under version option.

P.S. I guess you already know, but when you add version info into your deps file, you need to run vendors script, or if you're using composer use it to update dependencies.

Comment: yes, I saw that on the official docm that's why I'm asking, because I don't know how to specify , ' I want the latest version of 2.0.x' you see what I mean ? If I write v=2.0.x, my bash doesnt like it..

Comment: @MilesM. If you want 2.1.x branch you can specify it like this version=doctrine2.1.x or for 2.0.x branch like this version=doctrine2.0.x etc... Look on github page for gemo project list of tags and branches